# Завершение стримов RxJava при закрытии активности в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

Разбираюсь с использованием RxJava в Android, возник вопрос следующего рода. Я сделал вот такую extension функцию:

```
fun <T: View> T.setReactiveOnClickListener(): Flowable<View> {
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<View>()

    this.setOnClickListener {
        subject.onNext(it)
    }

    return subject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
}
```

Которую можно использовать следующим образом:

```
        btnBack
            .setReactiveOnClickListener()
            .map { finish() }
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при закрытии активности, стрим должен как-то об этом узнать и отмениться. Иначе это приведет к прямой утчке памяти. Я посмотрел возможные коллбеки View, ничего не нашел вроде onDestroy, где можно было бы отловить окончание жизни вьюхи. Конечно можно решить проблему в лоб и сделать централизованный стор стримов активности и явно дергать его очитску при закрытии активности, но как-то это не очень элегантное выглядит. Что можете предложить?

Comment: https://medium.com/@harshitbangar/rxjava-lifecycle-management-4330bcfdff6a

Answer (score 0):

То что вы пытаетесь написать - уже написано. [Посмотрите](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding4/view/ViewClickObservable.kt) как ваша задача реализована в [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). Если кратко - вам надо добавить убирание слушателя с View при прекращении действия подписки:

```
.doOnCancel { this.setOnClickListener(null) }
```

Метод doOnCancel должен быть вызван, когда актвити завершится. Это надо сделать вручную, например добавляя все подписки в CompositeDisposable, которому в onDestroy активити надо вызвать `dispose()`.

---

Либо, как указали в комментах - используйте [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nNU.png  к успеху идёте  https://i.stack.imgur.com/clilK.png   :)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ух, так вот почему у меня последнее время какая-то чертовщина творится - всё из-за репы))